# Determining optimal bins to bin the data

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, binning, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have X,Y data which i would like to bin according to X values.
However, I would like to determine the optimal number of X bins that satisfy a condition based on the resulting bin intervals and average Y of each bin. For example if i have

```
X=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

```
Y=[120,140,143,124,150,140,180,190,200]
```

I would like to determine the best number of X bins that will satisfy this condition:  Average of Y bin/(8* width of X bin) should be above 20, but as close as possible to 20. The bins should also be integers e.g., [1,2,..].
I am currently using:

```
bin_means, bin_edges, binnumber = binned_statistic(X, Y, statistic='mean', bins=bins)
```

with bins being pre-defined. However, i would like an algorithim that can determine the optimal bins for me before using this.
One can easily determine it for a small data but for hundreds of points it becomes time consuming.

Thank you

Comment: By "Average of Y bin" you mean the average of `bin_means`?

Comment: See if this helps... https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/798/275865

Comment: @RichieV yes, the averge of Y bin is the bin_means. I assume it has to be iterative. Thanks for the link you posted, it seems a similar problem but im interested in satisfying this special condition. Also it seems it gives answers in R language, which im not familiar with

Comment: hi there, did you make it work?

Comment: Hello @RichieV, I honestly did not continue working with your code. I managed to write a quite long code to do so. The idea is to start with wider bins and iteratively narrow them down until the condition is satisfied. I mean it is long but serves the job, im sure there are way more efficient ways. If interested, i can send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you NEED to iterate to find optimal `nbins` with your minimization function, take a look at numpy.digtize

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html

And try:

```
start = min(X)
stop = max(X)
cut_dict = {
    n: np.digitize(X, bins=np.linspace(start, stop, num=n+1))
    for n in range(min_nbins, max_nbins)}
    #input min/max_nbins
avg = {}
Y = pd.Series(Y).rename('Y')
avg = {nbins: Y.groupby(cut).mean().mean() for nbins, cut in cut_dict.items()}
avg = pd.Series(avg.values(), index=avg.keys()).rename('mean_ybins').to_frame()
```

Then you can find which is closest to 20 or if 20 is the right number...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Im trying to run it but i get an error     avg = {nbins: Y.groupby(cut).mean().mean() for nbins, cut in cut_dict.items}
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Right, should be`.items()` with parenthesis